# How to reset TextFields in a Scroll View

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

Through some fantastic help from a very patient user I managed to get my reset button working with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {

    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
            textField.text = @"";
        }

    }
```

The issue I am having now is that this will not reset the textfields in a scroll view. Any help will be gratefully received! I am so close to completing this!!!!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the method recursivly:

```
- (void)resetTextfieldsInView:(UIView*)view {

    for (UIView *v in [view subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)v;
            textField.text = @"";
        }else if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)v;
            textView.text = @"";
        }else{
            [self resetTextfieldsInView:v];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {
    [self resetTextfieldsInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textfields are embedded in a scroll view, then you need to iterate the subviews of the scroll view, i.e.

```
for (UIView *view in [self.scrollView subviews])
```